# Show that $A_5$ has no subgroup of order $20$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-actions, group-isomorphism

I have tried to solve it in the following way though I find little bit difficulty to reach at the desired conclusion.Here's my way.

I take the action of $A_5$ on the set of all left cosets of $H$ in $G$ by left multiplication where $H$ is the subgroup of order $20$ in $A_5$.Then this action induces a homomorphism from $A_5$ into $S_3$.If we observe the kernel of that homomorphism then we find that it either contains only the identity or it is whole of $A_5$ by the simplicity of $A_5$.But it cannot contain only the identity for which case we have a monomorphism from $A_5$ into $S_3$ which cannot be possible since $|A_5| > |S_3|$. So it is the whole of $A_5$.But here I got stuck.It may happen in which case the homomorphism becomes trivial.But to arrive at a contradiction I must have some argument which I have failed to crack in my mind.

Would anybody please help me in this regard for finding some way out.Then that will really help me a lot.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The homomorphism isn't trivial; its image must be transitive.

Comment: In my case there are in total three orbits each of size 1.Isn't it? Which contradicts the transitivity of this action.But how do I prove the transitive property of that action?

Comment: The kernel must be contained in $H$....

Comment: The transitivity of the action is easy to prove.

Comment: I got it. I forgot the thing that in this case the the kernel of the action is precisely $\cap_{x \in G}  xHx^{-1}$.

Comment: and also this action is transitive.